# Insert pictures in Word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

We have a Word document with about 100 pages and each page has two image frames in it. So we should insert 200 pictures in the document.

We need a VBA macro that reads a picture folder and places pictures in frames.

Picture names are in order like 001, 002, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to bring up an old one, but it might help somebody else, here is a macro that you should be able to adapt for your needs. This will copy the photos until there are no frames left, then exit, you may want to modify it to add a warning box if there are more photos than frames.

```
Sub AutoPicResize()
Dim iShp As InlineShape
Dim i As Integer
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Word.Application.ActiveDocument
        i = 1
        Max = ActiveDocument.Frames.Count
        For Each iShp In .InlineShapes
            If i > Max Then Exit For
            With iShp
                If .Type = wdInlineShapePicture Or wdInlineShapeLinkedPicture Then
                    iShp.Select
                    Selection.Cut
                    ActiveDocument.Frames(i).Select
                    Selection.Paste
                    i = i + 1
                End If
            End With
        Next iShp
    End With
    Word.Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```